# "How can I get any rest with all this excitement?" (Gerry Anderson/Supermarionation)

Tags: episode-identification, gerry-anderson

Years and years ago, I caught a snippet of what looked like a Gerry Anderson supermarionation show on TV. The only one of those I'm really familiar with is Thunderbirds, and this didn't look like any episode I recognized, so it must have been one of his other works. I remember exactly two things about this brief snippet:

- A shot of man in a wheelchair in a wide open, luxurious room. The space looked something like a fancy hotel lobby, with marble tiles in (I think) blacks and greens, some art and expensive-looking furniture. A man in a wheelchair (I think a sleek, black, then-futuristic motorised one) was riding up a shallow slope in the foreground.
- A woman's voice saying *"How can I get any rest with all this excitement?"*, or some variation thereupon (perhaps 'sleep' instead of 'rest'?). I believe this was heard while there was a close-up of a tape recorder in shot - perhaps some character in the episode had surreptitiously made an audio recording and was playing it back?

One note: there is a possibility that what I saw was not actually a full episode, but just a very short clip from one included as part of some kind of behind the scenes video/documentary. If this is true, the shot of the tape recorder may not have been an actual piece of episode footage at all, but behind the scenes footage of the audio recording/mixing process. If this is indeed the case, it would also be possible that the two pieces of information I remember are actually not connected at all, and were unrelated clips taken from separate episodes.

That's all I recall - and even then my recollection may not be 100% accurate. I'd be very interested to see whether anyone can identify the show/episode with such limited/information to go on.

EDIT: I really don't recall exactly when I saw this - it would probably have been 10-15 years ago, but I don't know exactly.

Comment: Possibly Commander Shore from *Stingray*

Comment: Like [this sort of tape recorder](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/gerry-anderson-thunderbirds-original-542696651)? Or something closer to a Walkman or Talkboy?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots It might well have been something like that, yes - I can't be sure.

Comment: I thought this might have been at the end of the music video for ‘Thunderbirds Are Go!’ by F.A.B. featuring MC Parker, but I’m watched it through, no dice.

Comment: Following on from @Paulie_D earlier, there was a compilation of three Stingray episodes with linking footage broadcast in 2008 or thereabouts: https://vimeo.com/533044429 . A few seconds after 12:30, we get "Sleep? The noise is deafening! I guess you're the doc", with a large tape recorder clearly present in the scene. Though it's a male voice, not female.

Comment: I misread that as "Super Mario Nation", and was confused.  :-)

Comment: @Drubbels Although the tape recorder isn't present, the "How can I get any rest with all this excitement" sounds a *bit* like a scene from Fireball XL5 episode 10 (The Space Pen). See 8:02 - 8:36 in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJSeZFVEmhE